Javascript POST request to ASP.NET Core Web API has been blocked by CORS policy (but not GET request)
I have an ASP.NET Core Web API written in C#, with CORS enabled.
I'm developing the frontend in react/javascript on another server and calling the Web API with fetch.
With the following POST request, I get an error:
fetch('http://servername:8082/api/company/createedit', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(formData)
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data))
    .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));  

Error:

Access to fetch at 'http://servername:8082/api/company/createedit' from origin 'http://localhost:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

But with the following GET request, I get the data and no CORS error:
fetch('http://servername:8082/api/company/getall')
    .then((response)=> response.json())
    .then((data) => { 
        setRequests(data.value); 
        console.log(data);
});

This is how I enabled CORS in the API - where am I wrong?
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

// CORS
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowAnyOrigin", builder =>
    {
        builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
               .AllowAnyMethod()
               .AllowAnyHeader();
    });
});

var app = builder.Build();
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
app.UseHttpsRedirection();

// CORS
app.UseCors("AllowAnyOrigin");

app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();

Update
I finally realized that I had misinterpreted the error.
The error was not related to the JsonResult response of the POST request.
Instead, a BadRequestObjectResult was returned due to an unhandled exception in the controller. The CORS error (missing 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' in the header) was detected on the BadRequestObjectResult.
By handling the exception and returning a JsonResult instead of the BadRequestObjectResult, the response is correctly configured with 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' in the header.
After some testing I realized that the instructions added on the Program.cs to enable CORS are not applied to the BadRequestObjectResult in case of an exception.

This is how I do it in Angular + .NetCore applications. Create a static extension class file say, AppConfigExtensions.cs and inside it put the following code:
public static class AppConfigExtensions
{
    public static WebApplication ConfigureCORS(this WebApplication app, IConfiguration config)
    {
        app.UseCors(t =>
        t.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader());

        return app;
    }
}

Then in your Program.cs file[remember there's no Startup.cs file in .NetCore 8] use the following
app.ConfigureCORS(builder.Configuration)

It works just fine for me.

To enable CORS in case of BadRequestObjectResult I found the following solution.
Create a custom attribute:
public class AddAccessControlAllowOriginAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (!(context.Result is JsonResult jsonResult))
        {
            var header = "Access-Control-Allow-Origin";
            var value = "http://localhost:5173"; // my front end origin
            if (context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.ContainsKey(header))
                context.HttpContext.Response.Headers[header] = value;
            else
                context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add(header, value);
        }
        base.OnResultExecuting(context);
    }
}

Apply to all controllers as follows:
[HttpPost]
[AddAccessControlAllowOriginAttribute]
public JsonResult CreateEdit(Company item)
{
    // ...
}

